# Is there a way to get MD5 Checksum from the files with a custom formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a Google Sheet full of important links to images on Google Drive. 
Is there a way to get MD5 Checksum from the files with a custom formula?

Here is my scenario:

```
No. | PHOTO            | MD5 CHECKSUM FROM PHOTO FROM G-DRIVE |

01  - LINK TO PHOTO 1  - MD5 CHECKSUM 1   
02  - LINK TO PHOTO 2  - MD5 CHECKSUM 2   
03  - LINK TO PHOTO 3  - MD5 CHECKSUM 3   
04  - LINK TO PHOTO 4  - MD5 CHECKSUM 4
```

Writing let's say `=CHECKSUM(C1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your script requires authorization in order to access Google Drive files. Custom Functions can't run services that require authorization but you could run your script from a

- Google Apps Script editor
- Installable trigger
- Custom menu
- Dialog
- Sidebar
- Web app

Regarding doing checksum on Google Drive files see [Google Drive MD5 checksum for files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23462168/1595451)

Comment: Yes, I need a script